# Does Java stop the world, when Lightweight Lock upgrade to Heavyweight Lock?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

As we know, when a Bias Lock upgrade to a Lightweight Lock, JVM will stop the world.

Does JVM stop the world, when Lightweight Lock upgrade to Heavyweight Lock?
And why?

Comment: The stop-the-world is necessary, when turning a Biased Lock to a Lightweight Lock, because the owner’s stack has to be searched. Since such a search is not necessary when turning to Heavyweight Lock, I don’t think that it needs a stop-the-world.

Comment: This would be an implementation detail - hence potentially dependent on JVM vendor and version - since this does not appear to be in the JVM or Java Language specifications.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a biased lock is to make locking/unlocking by a single thread as cheap as possible, ideally, zero cost. Locking/unlocking of a biased lock does not involve atomic operations, and therefore is not synchronized with other threads. So the revocation of a biased lock (e.g. because another thread wants to acuire it) requires an external synchronization mechanism. Stop-the-world pause is such a synchronization mechanism. It guarantees there is no race between threads.

On the contrary, locking/unlocking of a thin (lightweight) lock is a matter of an atomic Compare-And-Set operation. This CAS ensures synchronization (resolves races) between threads, so there is no need in an external synchronization mechanism.

An upgrade to a heavyweight lock also involves an atomic CAS of the object header. The JVM does not need to pause threads as long as they can communicate to each other through the "protocol" of atomic operations.

Comment: But why don't the revocation of a biased lock use the CAS operation? STW is too heavy. I heard another saying that, the revocation of a biased lock needs to change the stack of the thread, so it needs to STW.

Comment: @YuChan a CAS only ensures thread safety if all parties use it. As this answer explains, the thread using a biased lock doesn’t use CAS, avoiding it is the whole point of biased locking. If you find an object biased to a different thread, you don’t even know whether that thread currently owns the lock. That’s why there is no way around a stop-the-world. *If* the thread currently owns the lock, the header has to be adjusted to point to the owner thread’s lightweight lock structure which is on the owner thread’s stack. Yes, it’s expensive. It’s a trade-off. That’s why it is disabled by default.